# Java Output double in Scientific Notation

Tags: java, string, output

I got a weird case. I tried two different method to output the double number in Java. Let the result be a double number. The first one is :

```
DecimalFormat resFormat = new DecimalFormat("0.00E00f\n");
String strRes = resFormat.format(result);
if (strRes.contains("E-"))      strRes = strRes.replace("E", "e");
else                            strRes = strRes.replace("E", "e+");
```

The second one is:

```
String strRes = String.format("%3.2ef\n",result);
```

I am working on an OJ challenge for interest (in Chinese, http://ac.jobdu.com/problem.php?pid=1514). I tried. Keep all the other code completely the same, the first output passed all the test, while the second one lead to some error.

One output passed the test, while another failed. So the output of these two solutions must be different in some case, right? Why and when they are different?

PS: the input for both code segments is valid double numbers, neither NaN nor Infinity.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch One output passed the test, while another failed. So the output must be different in some case, right? Why they are different?

Comment: What is the test that the code fails?

Comment: Using a small letter 'e+' would make both lower casing and plus insertion superfluous. [Formatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax)

Comment: @Raedwald I am sorry. I really do not know the test case, making it failed. If I know, I could figure out why. It is more than a black-box test. Submit your code and only get "Right/Wrong". Two submissions, whose difference is ONLY these ouput code, have different result. One pass, while one failed. I am newbie in Java. So I posted it here for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try NaN, e.g.

```
result = 0.0/0.0;
```

The first format results in

```
NaNf
```

whereas the second produces something that prints on (my) stdout like this:

```
�
```

Which seems to be my "replacement character": 0xef 0xbf 0xbd when od'd.

From Javadoc of DecimalFormat: "NaN is formatted as a string, which typically has a single character \uFFFD. "

Similarly infinity:

```
result = 1.0/0.0;
```

Results are

```
Infinityf
```

and

```
 ∞f
```

You can (probably with a virtually unlimited) chance of success hunt for other differences. Here's a comparison,

```
static void cmp( double result ){
    String strRes1 = String.format("%3.2ef",result);
    DecimalFormat resFormat = new DecimalFormat("0.00E00f");
    String strRes2 = resFormat.format(result);
    if (strRes2.contains("E-"))  strRes2 = strRes2.replace("E", "e");
    else                         strRes2 = strRes2.replace("E", "e+");
    if( ! strRes1.equals( strRes2 ) ){
        System.out.println( strRes1 + " " + strRes2 );
        System.out.println( result );
    }
}
```

and now try to find some differences:

```
for( double x = 1.0; true; x /= 2.0 ){  // hit Ctrl-C to terminate the program
    cmp( x );
}

3.13e-02f 3.12e-02f
0.03125
1.27e-321f 1.26e-321f
1.265E-321
```

There is some difference w.r.t. rounding.

This is very nice, but what was the original question on that OJ site? Trying to fish for subtle differences in the JDK API is a rather weird challenge. You can bet that there are more interesting issues.

Comment: Thanks laune! But the input of these code is neither NaN nor Infinity. It was checked to make sure the number is a valide double.

Comment: How was this check made?

Comment: Found you some more diffs. What was the original question?

Comment: I did the computation by myself. And the input is not leading to Infinity. For NaN, I throw an exception, and catch outside. I completely have no idea what is wrong. Maybe the issue of the Online Judge system. I really appreciate your patienc and help!

Comment: You question is: is there any double number that could make the two codes output different thing? (not consider the NaN and Infinity).

Comment: Well, I've added a couple of non-NaN and non-Inf numbers that result in different String results. See my answer!

Comment: Thanks!!! The original question to to computer power without build-in or math library. And then output it. I get the comptutation done, but failed in the outputting.